# SVD command in Python v/s MATLAB

Tags: python, svd

I have  `m = 10, n = 5, A=randn(m,n);[U,S,V]=svd(A);` This returns a full 10x5 S matrix in MATLAB whereas Python only returns S as a 5x1 array. How do I recover the complete S matrix in Python? I have tried looking up several StackOverflow posts online but surprisingly doesn't shed light on this.

Also, how much does a Python IDE matter? I use Spyder but have been told that Vim is perhaps the most common.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To recover the Complete matrix you can do as follow :

```
import numpy as np
m = 10
n = 5
A=np.random.randn(m,n)
U,S,V =np.linalg.svd(A)
```

It's right that `S.shape = (5,)`.

You want something similar to https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svd.html with `A = 4x2` where final `S = 4×2` too.

To do that you define a matrix `B = np.zeros(A.shape)`. And you fill its diagonal with the element of S. By diagonal I mean where `i==j` as follow :

```
B = np.zeros(A.shape)
for i in range(m) :
    for j in range(n) :
        if i == j : B[i,j] = S[j]
```

Now `B.shape = (10,5)` as expected
Or in a more compact form :

```
C = np.array([[S[j] if i==j else 0 for j in range(n)] for i in range(m)])
```

I hope it helps

For the second question, I use gedit (standard text editor) running the code in [ipython](https://ipython.org/install.html) shell.

You can have a look to [jupyter](https://ipython.org/) too

Comment: Glad it helped ! feel free to up-vote or accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

The SVD of a matrix can be written as

```
A = U S V^H
```

Where the ^H signifies the [conjugate transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose). Matlab's `svd` command returns U, S and V, while `numpy.linalg.svd` returns U, the *diagonal* of S, and V^H. Thus, to get the same S and V as in Matlab you need to reconstruct the S and also get the V:

```
import numpy

m = 10
n = 5
A = numpy.random.randn(m, n)
U, sdiag, VH = numpy.linalg.svd(A)
S = numpy.zeros((m, n))
numpy.fill_diagonal(S, sdiag)
V = VH.T.conj()  # if you know you have real values only you can leave out the .conj()
```

Comment: This returns S as a 5x5 matrix but S is actually 10x5 (though the last 5 rows are null) We need to add those null rows manually, then?

Comment: I found diagflat does the job too!